# Possible tag blacklist candidates

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we merge mobilephones with cellphones?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/663/should-we-merge-mobilephones-with-cellphones)

I've been digging around in Tags quite a bit (mostly to write wikis for them) and have been running across several that probably shouldn't be allowed to exist.

[smartphones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphones) Android phones are, by definition, smartphones. While Android exists on other devices (Google TV, tablets, Android x86) this tag doesn't seem to serve any useful purpose. At best, I could see an [android-phone] tag to distinguish a question as being about phones *only*, but this tag doesn't make sense to me.

[cellphones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellphones) Similar to "smartphone" above.

Answer (score -1):

Could you create [meta-smartphones] as a synonym of [android-phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-phone), [cellphones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellphones) or [phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phone)...

Or to put it another way, have [android-phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-phone) and make the other two synonyms of it.

Comment: I suppose, but to what end? We're considering tags that shouldn't exist on the site. Why make a synonym of a blacklisted tag instead of just blacklisting it? Or am I not grokking what you're saying?

Comment: @Al Everett, I guess I was saying that if the tag is semi correct (a phone) because technically you might have an Android phone question then why not have many of the 'phone derivatives' as synonyms which takes care of them not being shown and automatically correcting them when used...