# Should we merge mobilephones with cellphones?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I don't see any difference between [mobile-phones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) and [cellphones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellphones). Should we merge them? :)

Comment: They should be blacklisted IMO.  (In the meantime I've merged them.)

Comment: @MatthewRead what's the advantage of blacklisting?

Comment: They're useless tags, really.  1 was closed in `mobile-phones` and I just closed 4 more.  People tend to use them for shopping recommendations, or just at random because they're technically asking about a cell phone.  If they are asking a valid question that generally applies to Android phones, they should use tags about the specific issue rather than `android`, `cellphones`, `general-question` or the like.

Comment: @MatthewRead A false tagged question is one thing. But on the other side I see no harm done when using this tag appropriate. A good example for [tag:cellphone] would be [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14625/on-which-android-tablets-is-gsm-telephony-feasible). And I am sure that there are other questions about the cellphone functionality too.

Comment: It's not about cellphones, that would only be confusing.  The particular phone functionality in question is calling, covered by the `calls` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've merged `smartphones` under `mobile-phones` (which was merged with `cellphones` as noted).

Only one question tagged with `smartphones` could be argued to deserve it.  People seem to use these tags when they have a question about **a** phone, rather than a general question applicable to many phones, which is silly.  `tablet` is a little better (probably because there are fewer of them) but we should keep an eye on it.

I didn't seen more than one or two `smartphones`/`mobile-phones`/`cellphones` questions that were actually about hardware, so I don't think merging them under `hardware` is necessarily a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

[phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phone) and [phone-hardware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phone-hardware) are synonyms of [hardware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware). Perhaps these should be as well?

And what about [smartphones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphones)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about [smartphones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphones). But there is also [tablet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablet), so maybe it makes sense to keep the smartphone tag also.

I am in favor of blacklisting [mobile-phones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) and [cellphones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellphones). Matthew is right: If the phone functionality in question is calling, [calls](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calls) is the tag to go. And for everything else, [mobile-phones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) and [cellphones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellphones) is to broad and inaccurate.